# Error symbol at project icon in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

Recently I **imported a new project** to **Eclipse** Indigo IDE.

Initially there is **no error symbol in Project root directory**. When I tried to run the JUnit test it shows an **error in the Project root directory Icon**.

I can't find the error anywhere in the project. When I try to run a JUnit file it shows a warning that there are errors in the project, when I Click Proceed they run without any problem.

But there is an error somewhere around there.

*Any reason why Eclipse exhibits this strange behaviour ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there some more details shown in the 'Problems' view?

I have had similar issues when some redundant files (jars, libraries) were mentioned, but not found in project build path.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah there is an error shown in the Problems View. The project was not built due to error(permission) in accessing a folder for build. Cause I am using CentOS.